# How to find an HTML Object in C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a 3rd part control(it is a COM and it is not a server control).

```
 <object id="SigPlus1" classid="clsid:69A40DA3-4D42-11D0-86B0-0000C025864A" 
            name="SigPlus1" style="left: 0px; width: 544px; top: 0px; height: 86px">
    <param name="_Version" value="131095">
       <param name="_ExtentX" value="14393">
         <param name="_ExtentY" value="2275">
            <param name="_StockProps" value="9"></param>
         </param>
        </param>
    </param>
   </object>
```

In the C# code behind I use:

```
object o = (Page.FindControl("SigPlus1")
```

There is no error but o is set to null.

I know this object has a property named colormode, how can set this in the code behind

Comment: You don't have `runat="server"` on that tag, that means it's not a control and therefore `FindControl` isn't going to find it.

Comment: also your casting is off take a look at msdn [Page.FindControl method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `runat="server"` attribute to the `<object>` element. Then you can find it in the code behind.

```
<object id="SigPlus1" runat="server" ...>
```

Code behind

```
var SigPlus1 = Page.FindControl("SigPlus1");
```

Or if the control is not in a templated control you can access it directly via it's ID without needing `Page.FindControl()`.

Comment: This tag, somehow does not let to add runat server. I asked the dev person why and he told me because this is a COM control(interop)

Comment: @SNash what do you mean does not let you? Need details.

Comment: Im on the bus but I post tge error messae as soo as i get home.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `runat = "server"`

```
<object id="SigPlus1" runat="server" classid="clsid:69A40DA3-4D42-11D0-86B0-0000C025864A" name="SigPlus1" style="left: 0px; width: 544px; top: 0px; height: 86px">
```

and if you dont want to add the runat = "server" then you can use like

```
var SigPlus1 = Request.Form["SigPlus1"];
```

Comment: `var SigPlus1 = Request.Form["SigPlus1"];` would only get posted form values. It wouldn't get a control reference.

Comment: @mason:- Yes very correct! The the only option is to have runat = "server"

Comment: I cannot run it as server i get an error. I include the error message as soon as i get to my computer

Comment: In order to change to using 'Runat=server': The above answer should have mentioned that all current page script references, if any exist, in your aspx page, need to be converted to this example format `document.getElementByID('<%=SigPlus1.ClientID%>')`